# network issue after using macchanger. no internet, no ipv4

Tags: networking, ip, mac-address, dhcp

I used `macchanger` with these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo macchanger -r eth0 
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

I am using it with virtualbox on a local network, I've never had issue with that before, however now once I do that I lose internet.

the issue goes away when I reboot the machine as the MAC address reset to default. tried to reboot the router also, and my Linux works perfectly fine until I reset its MAC address.

`ifconfig` shows no ipv4 for `eth0`, restarting network-manager does not help.  either.

**Troubleshooting done without success :**

Tried different hardware: computer, router and fresh install of
virtualbox and Kali.

Tried to use the older version of virtualbox.

`service network-manager restart`, `macchanger -e -r`, `dhclient eth0`.

Changed /etc/network/interfaces for eth0 with dhcp then for oreth0 static.

Tried different network settings on virtualbox.

Checked the firewall disabled local and gateway.

Reinstalled network-manager.

ping 8.8.8.8 return " this site can't be reached".

Comment: Hey Benjy - More info would help. Is this on a local network behind a home router, corporate network or directly connected to a DOCSIS cable modem? Regardless have you restarted the next hop in the network?

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit directly on `network-manager`:
Right click on

> Network-Manager -> Edit Connections -> Choose the adapter "wifi or wired" -> ...

...then edit the MAC ADDRESS of the adapter selected.
If it worked, please feedback to us.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- If you're fresh install is actually clean from the distro, then it makes me think your wifi password is bad (if on wlan) or you have a wiring/switch/gateway issue.
- If you're chaining your mac, it makes me think you're on a VM with a virtual switch to your host. Confirm from your host that you have connectivity to the wan. `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping 4.2.2.1` to see if you can reach out.
- Sounds like there may be a layer 2 access control at the gateway/switch. Login if you have creds and confirm that there isn't a mac whitelist in place.
- Check your local/network firewall. Try disabling the local and/or gateway firewall for a quick second to see if the problem goes away.
- There could be a packet MTU setting issue, but that is not very likely. Steps to troubleshoot that would be a bit advanced.
- If you also control the gateway/switch, try resetting them as well. You're clearly willing to blow away your box to fix this, so maybe you'd be willing to reset them as well.
- Look into which services your flavor of *nix needs for networking. Example: https://theos.in/desktop-linux/tip-that-matters/how-do-i-restart-linux-network-service/. It could be that one of these services was disabled, and needs to be enabled.

Comment: Changing the MAC address for purposes of spoofing another user's MAC to bypass certain access controls might be one reason

Comment: Hence the assumption on line 4...

Comment: OP does not have an IP - that makes half of your suggestions unworkable

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't address your NIC through eth0 because of the MAC address is 00:00:00:00:00:00 isn't it ?
You can't save any configuration for your nic, you can't use it, that's why you have the same problem using a different Linux distribution.
It's a hardware problem i'm afraid, not software